# AWS CloudWatch Dashboard sharing

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using boto3 (Python SDK for AWS) to create a CloudWatch Dashboard for specific clients. The only thing I cannot find an API for is sharing the dashboard with others via email.  I can do it from the AWS console, but I cannot find any API that will return the shareable link.  I think I can do the permissions with the Cognito and IAM but am stumped on the link and hoping there is an API that does what the console does. Has anyone done this or seen any reference in the API docs?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using Boto3 as it does not provide API for sharing Dashboard.
Though, you can use console to do this, refer below blog that has much information.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/share-your-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboards-with-anyone-using-aws-single-sign-on/